# OpenGL Multisampling doesn't work

Tags: opengl, sdl2, antialiasing

I am trying to get the Antialiasing (multisampling) in OpenGL with SDL to work([as shown here](http://adrianboeing.blogspot.com/2010/01/antialiasing-multisampling-opengl-with.html)), but the result doesn't change and I still get jaggy edges.

Before rendering I call the following functions

```
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
```

As I've been looking for a solution I added more functions to my SDL setup but nothing helped.

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, 0);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);


SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 4);
        
SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1" );
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
```

Window and Context are created via

```
window = SDL_CreateWindow(Window_title.str().c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, flags);
SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
```

Any Ideas what I could do to get around this? Should I try a different approach for anti-aliasing?

Have I missed something about Multisampling / anti-aliasing, like there's an extra fragment shader needed or so?

[image: Image from my Game showing the aliased edges]

Comment: At best, multi-sampling will help only at the polygon edges. It won't do anything for the aliasing of individual texels in your nearest-neighbour filtered texture. So you'll want a different solution there, at minimum.

Comment: but I thought MSAA would at least smooth out the edges of the cubes...

Comment: @DMGregory♦
 do you have any recommendations what technique I could use to get rid of the aliasing of the texels inside the texture?

Comment: [This recent question links to a couple of such methods](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/200153/39518).